# How to make alert with a alert in fragment?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When I'm executing the below script, i got error `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

```
public void EditDaytoDayTask(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Inside editdaytoday");
        //((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);

        final String taskName=bundle.getString("TASKDAYTODAY");
        Log.i(TAG,"TAsknamedate:"+taskName+" "+date);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertViewTaskDescription=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflaterViewTaskDescription=(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         viewTaskWithDescription=(View)inflaterViewTaskDescription.inflate(R.layout.viewtaskwithdescriptionlayout,null,false);

        TextView textviewTask=(TextView)viewTaskWithDescription.findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayView);
        TextView textviewDescription=(TextView)viewTaskWithDescription.findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayView);
        textviewTask.setText(taskName);
        final String descriptionTask=objTaskDb.FetchDescriptionTask(date,taskName);
        textviewDescription.setText(descriptionTask);
        alertViewTaskDescription.setView(viewTaskWithDescription);
        alertViewTaskDescription.setPositiveButton("EDIT",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertEditTaskDescription=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                LayoutInflater inflaterEditTaskDescription=(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View viewEditTaskDescription=(View)inflaterEditTaskDescription.inflate(R.layout.edittaskwithdescriptionlayout,null,false);
                //((ViewGroup)viewEditTaskDescription.getParent()).removeAllViews();
                EditText edittextTask=(EditText)viewEditTaskDescription.findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayEdit);
                EditText edittextDescription=(EditText)viewEditTaskDescription.findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayEdit);
                edittextTask.setText(taskName);
                edittextDescription.setText(descriptionTask);
                alertEditTaskDescription.setView(edittextDescription);
                alertEditTaskDescription.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

        alertViewTaskDescription.show();

    }
}
```

How to solve this error? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are adding some view into another view .But view you are adding is already a child of someview .So basically you have to call removeview on parent .At which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: i have one create view and the above two view in inner class for call back purpose.

Comment: My first alert dialog having two text view and then i press the edit button in the alertbox it shows another alertbox with two edittext instead of textview....Thanks

Comment: i got error in alertViewTaskDescription.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai i find this error and solve it.This is my simple mistake add edit text instead of view in setview.I change

```
alertEditTaskDescription.setView(viewEditTaskDescription);

instead of this

 alertEditTaskDescription.setView(edittextDescription);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me..

```
public void EditDaytoDayTask() {
        // Log.i(TAG,"Inside editdaytoday");
        //((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);

        //final String taskName=bundle.getString("TASKDAYTODAY");
        //Log.i(TAG,"TAsknamedate:"+taskName+" "+date);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertViewTaskDescription=new AlertDialog.Builder(hostActReference);
        LayoutInflater inflaterViewTaskDescription=(LayoutInflater)hostActReference.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewTaskWithDescription = (View)inflaterViewTaskDescription.inflate(R.layout.pdf_save_dialog,null,false);

        //TextView textviewTask=(TextView)viewTaskWithDescription.findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayView);
        //TextView textviewDescription=(TextView)viewTaskWithDescription.findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayView);
        //textviewTask.setText(taskName);
        //final String descriptionTask=objTaskDb.FetchDescriptionTask(date,taskName);
        // textviewDescription.setText(descriptionTask);
        alertViewTaskDescription.setView(viewTaskWithDescription);
        alertViewTaskDescription.setPositiveButton("EDIT",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertEditTaskDescription=new AlertDialog.Builder(hostActReference);

                LayoutInflater inflaterEditTaskDescription=(LayoutInflater)hostActReference.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View edittextDescription=(View)inflaterEditTaskDescription.inflate(R.layout.save_dialog,null,false);
                //((ViewGroup)viewEditTaskDescription.getParent()).removeAllViews();
                //EditText edittextTask=(EditText)viewEditTaskDescription.findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayEdit);
                //  EditText edittextDescription=(EditText)viewEditTaskDescription.findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayEdit);
                //edittextTask.setText(taskName);
                //edittextDescription.setText(descriptionTask);
                alertEditTaskDescription.setView(edittextDescription);
                alertEditTaskDescription.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    }
                });

                alertEditTaskDescription.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                alertEditTaskDescription.create().show();

            }
        });

        alertViewTaskDescription.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);


        alertViewTaskDescription.create().show();


    }
```

Comment: hai i find this error,which is in alertEditTaskDescription.setView(edittextDescription); line. because i gave the wrong parameter edittextDescription instead of viewEdittextDescription.

Comment: hai msn i need one help.i have listview with two text view.When i load the program only one textview visible and i click the list item other one is view.This is working but when i am click the another list item the above one hide and new one open.for example collapsed function in expandable list view.